# Access file system in Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I need to encode video using ffmpeg in Service Fabric service when I receive new message from Service Bus queue. I can extract ffmpeg.exe from resources and run it but can I save input/output video files in internal file system?

Answer (score 5):

I tested it on local cluster by following code:

```
    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            string filename = "testFile.txt";
            File.AppendAllText(filename, "test. ");

            string content = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Content:" + content);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(new FileInfo(filename).FullName);

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

The result output was:

```
Content:test. 
C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_3\SampleAppType_App51\work\testFile.txt
Content:test. test. 
C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_3\SampleAppType_App51\work\testFile.txt
Content:test. test. test. 
C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_3\SampleAppType_App51\work\testFile.txt
```

But path was changed on the next run to C:\SfDevCluster\Data_App_Node_3\SampleAppType_App52\work\testFile.txt.

So I suppose the answer is:

It's possible to use local file system but only for temporary files. And I think it's a good practice to clean up the system at the end of iteration.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. Temporary local file storage is as far as you want to go with local file system because services are not tied to any specific VM instance.